# Why does delayed animation not synchronize with for loop?

Tags: swift, multithreading

I have an array of elements that I want to animate. I add a delay per increment in the index. However, some elements animate at the same time (Usually two at a time) .

I'm not sure if it is because the for loop isn't iterating at a constant speed, or if the main thread has too many calls to it?

*Note - the flipCard is not the problem. If I just set the cell.alpha = 0, the problem still persists.

Gif with problem -- 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EJRF.jpg

```
private func animateCells() {
    if collectionView.visibleCells.count < indexToFlip { return }
    let numberOfCards = collectionView.visibleCells.count
    var currentIndex = 1
    var delayNextFlipMiliSeconds = 0
    for section in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
            guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as? CardCell else { continue }
            print(delayNextFlipMiliSeconds)
            print(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(delayNextFlipMiliSeconds)) {
                cell.flipCard() {
                    currentIndex += 1
                    if currentIndex == numberOfCards {
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                            self.playButton.alpha = 1
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            delayNextFlipMiliSeconds += 200
        }
    }
}
```

Debug prints..

```
0
1547749398.849406
200
1547749398.850255
400
1547749398.850312
600
1547749398.850347
800
1547749398.8503752
1000
1547749398.850401
1200
1547749398.850429
1400
1547749398.850459
1600
1547749398.850482
1800
1547749398.850504
2000
1547749398.850525
2200
1547749398.850559
2400
1547749398.850597
2600
1547749398.85063
2800
1547749398.850657
3000
1547749398.850702
```

Comment: Did you try using `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` with a delay value instead of using GCD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DispatchQueue.main is a serial queue that ensures that the tasks will be executed in the order in which they are added to the queue. However dispatch_async return after it is added to the queue and may not have finished yet, and rest of the code (for loop) starts executing.

What's happening is, that "for" loops are putting multiple blocks of code (tasks) in main queue, that will be executed in order but execution timing may depend on the availability of processor. Some task may get schedule quickly than others. The scheduler schedules the task at run time and can not be predicted. Thats why you see its not executed at regular interval.

You can try something like

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delayNextFlipMiliSeconds, repeats: false) { (timer) in
         DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                //Your Code
            }
    }.fire()
```

Using DispatchQueue.main.sync will ensure that "Your Code" gets executed first, then will be go to the rest of the code. However, using DispatchQueue.main.sync will also slow your UI from user's points of view, but i think that will be negligible.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how the main queue handles the execution order. However if we are using a timer I do not see the need to use the DispatchQueue.main at all?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use UIView.animate() with a completion handler? This way you can hand off the next animation directly, when the first has finished.

Comment: I want to start the next animation in the middle of the previous one's, not after it has been complete.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to not care about GCD or the for loop time and use a timer instead. It works perfectly.

```
private func animateCells() {
    var cells: [CardCell] = []
    for section in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
            guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as? CardCell else { continue }
            cells.append(cell)
        }
    }
    var animationIndex = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        cells[animationIndex].flipCard()
        animationIndex += 1
        if animationIndex ==  cells.count {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.playButton.alpha = 1
            })
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }.fire()
}
```